# Worklight 7.1 installation hanging on Eclipse Mars - 7.1.0.0-MFPF-StudioP2-IF201512271725

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Trying to install worklight studio 7.1.0.0-MFPF-StudioP2-IF201512271725 on my eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) but for some reason the archive installation is hanging at org.eclipse.jst. please refer screen shot attached, Can anyone please suggest what could be done to resolve this[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always suggested to use the latest. Right now you're not doing.

You can get the latest from Eclipse by clicking on Help -> Eclipse Marketplace and search for "mobilefirst".

Alternatively if you are an IBM customer you can visit the IBM Fix Central website and download the latest available iFix for the Studio component.

Comment: Hi I am now using market place to install Worklight 7.1 but the installation is hanging at the same place, any idea suggestions ?

Comment: Are you sure it is hanging or just being extremely slow? We can't do anything about that.

Comment: I think the issue is with eclipse MARS version, i just used eclipse kepler and its downloading all the bits.

Comment: Seing a new error now , An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.ws.st.common.core,1.0.200.v20150617_2241.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: d867a7d3df78c8b9fdc6ab928a0e6759 and found 0afe3025b49af98988b5acdcf5ea74a4.

Comment: Finally Worked, I took the released version of 7.1.0.00.20160528-1648 and installed that on my kepler version.